Unable to run bitbucket pipeline
I was trying to deploy code to my ec2 instance from bitbucket
image: node:slim
pipelines:
    branches:
        dev:
            - step:
                  name: Install dependency package and build
                  caches:
                      - node
                  script:
                      - yarn
                      - yarn build
                  artifacts:
                      - node_modules/**
                      - dist/**
            - step:
                  name: Deploy build folder to server via Rsync
                  script:
                      - pipe: atlassian/rsync-deploy:0.13.0
                        variables:
                            USER: $USER
                            SERVER: $SERVER
                            SSH_KEY: $MY_SSH_KEY
                            DEBUG: 'true'
                            REMOTE_PATH: '/home/ubuntu/api/dist'
                            LOCAL_PATH: 'dist/*'
            - step:
                  name: Deploy node_modules to server via Rsync
                  script:
                      - pipe: atlassian/rsync-deploy:0.13.0
                        variables:
                            USER: $USER
                            SERVER: $SERVER
                            SSH_KEY: $MY_SSH_KEY
                            DEBUG: 'true'
                            REMOTE_PATH: '/home/ubuntu/api/node_modules'
                            LOCAL_PATH: 'node_modules/*'
            - step:
                name: Set execute permissions
                script:  
                  - pipe: atlassian/ssh-run:0.8.1
                    variables:
                      SSH_USER: $USER
                      SERVER: $SERVER
                      SSH_KEY: $MY_SSH_KEY
                      COMMAND: 'chmod +x /home/ubuntu/api/deploy.sh'
            - step:
                name: Run deploy script
                script:  
                  - pipe: atlassian/ssh-run:0.8.1
                    variables:
                      SSH_USER: $USER
                      SERVER: $SERVER
                      SSH_KEY: $MY_SSH_KEY
                      COMMAND: 'cd /home/ubuntu/api/ && ls'

above code works fine. and i got following result in from the last step
Status: Downloaded newer image for bitbucketpipelines/ssh-run:0.8.1
INFO: Executing the pipe...
INFO: Using passed SSH_KEY
INFO: Executing command on $SERVER
ssh -A -tt -i /root/.ssh/pipelines_id -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -p 22 $USER@$SERVER bash -c 'cd /home/$USER/api/ && ls'
Dockerfile       ecosystem.config.js  test
README.md        nest-cli.json        tsconfig.build.json
bitbucket-pipelines.yml  node_modules         tsconfig.build.tsbuildinfo
deploy.sh        package-lock.json    tsconfig.json
dist             package.json         yarn.lock
docker-compose.yml   src
Connection to $SERVER closed.

but when i try to run my project in to the remote server(ec2 instance).
lets say i change the last step as following
- step:
                name: Run deploy script
                script:  
                  - pipe: atlassian/ssh-run:0.8.1
                    variables:
                      SSH_USER: $USER
                      SERVER: $SERVER
                      SSH_KEY: $MY_SSH_KEY
                      COMMAND: 'cd /home/ubuntu/api/ && yarn && yarn buuld'

it shows error yarn not found (Though my remote server has everything i can run it manually.)
i tried with a deploy.sh script the problem remains same.
Following works fine:
image: node:slim

pipelines:
    branches:
        dev:
          - step:
                  name: Start application using PM2
                  script:
                      - pipe: atlassian/ssh-run:0.8.1
                        variables:
                            SSH_USER: $USER
                            SERVER: $SERVER
                            COMMAND: 'cd /home/ubuntu/api && ls && echo $PATH && /bin/bash git pull origin dev'
          - step:
                  name: Deploying build 
                  variable:
                      USER: $USER
                      SERVER: $SERVER
                  script:
                      - yarn
                      - yarn build
                      - cd /home/ubuntu/api
                      - npm install pm2 -g
                      - pm2 start 

It working and i can found that my ec2 instance has been updated with latest code from bitbucket but now still step 2 not working.

Do you have yarn installed so the SSH user can use it?

@Randommm image: node:slim does it comes with yarn i guess it should ?

You are running on your server, how is it setup there

@Randommm please have a look I have updated the question from Following, which works fine. Maybe you can help

To fix the issue where yarn is not found during deployment via Bitbucket Pipelines on your EC2 instance, follow these steps:
Use a login shell to load environment variables: Update your command to run in a login shell so it loads the necessary paths (e.g., for yarn):

step:
name: Run deploy script
script:
- pipe: atlassian/ssh-run:0.8.1
variables:
SSH_USER: $USER
SERVER: $SERVER
SSH_KEY: $MY_SSH_KEY
COMMAND: 'cd /home/ubuntu/api/ && bash -lc "yarn && yarn build"'
Alternatively, specify the full path to yarn: Find the full path of yarn using which yarn, and use that path in the command:

COMMAND: 'cd /home/ubuntu/api/ && /usr/local/bin/yarn && /usr/local/bin/yarn build'
This ensures yarn is found and executed correctly during deployment

From my finding, i have figured it out, pipeline runs on Docker and there is no yarn by default

This is the full workable code
image: atlassian/default-image:4

pipelines:
  branches:
    dev:
      - step:
          name: Install Dependencies & Deploy
          script:
            - echo "Setting up SSH agent..."
            # Run deployment script on the remote server
            - ssh -v $USER@$SERVER 'cd /home/ubuntu/api && ls && echo $PATH && /bin/bash deploy.sh'

Here is my deploy.sh
echo "Deploy script started"
cd /home/ubuntu/api
node -version
sh pull.sh
echo "Deploy script finished execution"

and here is the pull.sh
git pull origin dev

#!/bin/bash

echo "Deploy script started"

# Set the PATH explicitly (if needed)
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin


# Install Node.js and Yarn
echo "Installing Node.js and Yarn..."
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y curl
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_20.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
sudo npm install -g yarn
sudo npm install -g pm2
# Display installed versions of Node.js and Yarn for debugging
node -v
yarn -v

# Pull latest changes from the dev branch
echo "Pulling latest changes from dev branch..."
git pull origin dev

# Install dependencies and build the application
echo "Installing dependencies and building the application..."
yarn install
yarn build

echo "Deploy script finished execution"




# yarn 
# yarn build
pm2 start

